# When define an array, what is the diffrence on performance between define in main function and callee function?

Tags: c++, c

Consider:
[1]

```
int *func(){
int a[10];
//...
return a;
}

int main(){
int* a = func();
} 
//在函数里开数组后往main函数回传指针
```

[2]

```
void func(int a*){
//...
}
int main(){
int a[10];
func(a);
}
//在main函数开个数组后传实参到函数里
```

Two programs can define an array `a` and use it. Which one is better? Why?在内存分配和性能上有啥区别?更推荐哪种方式?

Comment: 1 is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: _"Why?在内存分配和性能上有啥区别?更推荐哪种方式?"_ futile to ask for case one, in case 2 it's just uninitialized values,  accessing uninitialized values is _UB_ as well.

Comment: _"Two programs can define an array a and use it."_ You're wrong about this. It's _undefined behavior_ as mentioned. That your programs compile and run, doesn't mean they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Two codes can define an array a and use it.Which one is better? Why?

The second is better because the first is plain broken. You return a pointer to an array that will no longer exist once the function returns. In other words a dangling pointer.

Comment: Truly thanks. I thought the action will be similar to the struct-pointers...

Answer (score 0):

Neither is what I would do in C++
I would use one of those constructs:

```
#include <array>

void function(int values[10])
{
}

template<std::size_t N>
void function_template(int(&values)[N])
{
}

template<std::size_t N>
void function_const_ref(const std::array<int, N>& arr) // pass by const reference if you only want to use values
{
}

template<std::size_t N>
void function_ref(std::array<int, N>& arr)
{
    arr[1] = 42;
}


int main()
{
    int arr[10]{};  // {} also initializes all values to 0!

    function(arr);
    function_template(arr); // keeps working even if you change size from 10 to something else

    // or use std::array and you ca
    std::array<int, 10> arr2{};
    function_ref(arr2);

    // this is I think the most C++ way
    function_const_ref(arr2);

    return 0;
}
```